# Error on update table by ajax , jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a piece of code for update a table but it does not work. When I click on send button the page will refresh but **not affected** on table record and **not redirect**.
For debugging I've added alert to my code but in Inspect view of my browser I couldn't find data.operation value!

```
 $(document).on('click', '#send', function() {            
        data._id = $(this).attr("id");
        data.operation = "send";            
        alert('hello');
        $.ajax({
            url: "updatedetail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $.redirect('order3.html', {
                    'orderid': _id
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

//updatedetail.php

```
if ($_POST['operation'] == 'send') {
    $query = "UPDATE orders SET status=:sid WHERE id=:id";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(':sid', 2);
    $statement->bindParam(':id', $_POST['_id']);
    $result = $statement->execute();


    if (!empty($result)) {
        echo "data updated";
    }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: I'd recommend moving your debugging to the first instruction if it is not firing. Using the browser debugger or console.log is recommended as well. I think the way you are populating the data variable is the issue. It should be created inside the [ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) call, like data: { _id = $(this).attr("id"), operation: "send" }

Answer (score 0):

try using this error logging in ajax

```
error: function (request, status, error) {
   console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

Comment: This should have been a comment as its not an answer to "Whats wrong"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#send', function() {            
        data._id = $(this).attr("id");
        data.operation = "send";            
        alert('hello');
        $.ajax({
            url: "updatedetail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(resp) {
               if(resp == 1){
                 location.reload();
               }else{ alert(resp);}`enter code here`
            }
        });
    });
```

use this as code for ajax and in your update file use
return 1 and you should be able to reload the page with updated table or get a error from your update php file